# laravel QueryException table not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am not getting it that why i am facing it.

I created a migration name `2018_01_12_035551_create_inquiry_master_table` 
In my route file assign a route `Route::get('lists-inquiry','InquiryController@listinquiry')->name('lists-inquiry');`

Created a controller name `InquiryController`

Controller code:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\InquiryMaster;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class InquiryController extends BaseController
{
public function listinquiry() {
    $inquiry = InquiryMaster::all();
    // dd($inquiry) Here i am getting error
    return view('admin.list_inquiry')->with('listinquiry', $inquiry);
}
}
```

Created a model `InquiryMaster`

My model look like:

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class InquiryMaster extends Model
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'created_date_time',
    'user_id',
    'stitch_video_path',
    'completion_status'
];

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */

}
```

When i dd($inquiry)  in controller it returns error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bigball_travel.inquiry_masters' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `inquiry_masters`)

It shows table  `inquiry_masters`

and i created `inquiry_master`

Comment: In your model add ```protected $table="inquiry_master";``` otherwise follow the default table naming convention that laravel follow, rename the table 'inquiry_masters', in second scenario you don't have to explicitly mention the table name in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `protected $table = 'inquiry_master';` to InquiryMaster model

so class would look like this.

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class InquiryMaster extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'inquiry_master';

    protected $fillable = [
        'created_date_time',
        'user_id',
        'stitch_video_path',
        'completion_status'
    ];

}
```

Comment: thanx it work. But why adding `protected $table = 'inquiry_master';` in model. Implemented other module in same project but didnt face this type issue.

Comment: laravel expects the table name to be plural of model unless specified otherwise. if it worked can you please mark it as the right answer

Comment: usefull infrmation.yes marked as a right answer.+1 for my question);-